# How to include an ember js helper function inside a handlebars expression

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to include a helper `myHelper` inside a `link-to` expression like below but it seems you cannot have an expression directly inside another expression.

`{{# link-to "someUrl" class="txt-dark-1 {{myHelper data}}"}}
  Some text
{{/link-to}}`

How could you include a helper function in this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the value of your helper directly, you can call your helper via `()` instead of `{}` like this:

```
{{# link-to "someUrl" class="txt-dark-1" (myHelper data) }}
  Some text
{{/link-to}}
```

If you want to concat another string value to your class attribute, you can use it via `concat` helper like this:

```
{{# link-to "someUrl" class=(concat "txt-dark-1 " (myHelper data)) }}
  Some text
{{/link-to}}
```